# Why promise.then() behaves asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In the below code why `promise.then()` behaves asynchronously. In other words , why browser is not waiting for the code written inside `promise.then()` method to be executed?.What tell the browser engine so that `promise.then()` makes an asynchronous call?

```
const money = 500;

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(money > 400){
        resolve('You have a car!');
    }else{
        reject('Yo do not have enough money to buy the Car!');
    }
});
console.log('Before');
promise.then(function(data){
    console.log('Success '+data);
});
console.log('After');
```

The above code prints the output in the below order, which means promise.then() works asynchronously.

- Before
- After
- Success You have a car!

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, and the callback function in `then()` is queued first.

Comment: Promises are supposed to be asynchronous.  You can force them to wait by means of the `await` command.

Comment: It is just what promise.then does.

Comment: but there is no event loop like how it is being used for setTimeout function.

Answer (score 2):

Promise is asynchronous

You can use await like this to make synchronous

```
const money = 500;

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    if(money > 400){
        resolve('You have a car!');
    }else{
        reject('Yo do not have enough money to buy the Car!');
    }
});
console.log('Before');

let data = await promise
console.log('Success '+data);
console.log('After');
```

To get result

```
Before
Success You have a car!
After
```

Comment: but there is no event loop like how it is being used for setTimeout function. If you execute the code here - latentflip.com/loupe/ you could see no event loop is running. I was under the assumption that there is an event loop behind every asynchronous call.